# '' ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: " How to fix this?

Tags: python

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lnzycfzs\\sendkeys\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lnzycfzs\\sendkeys\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ak2dcxbs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
     cwd: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-lnzycfzs\sendkeys\
Complete output (17 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
copying SendKeys.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
running build_ext
building '_sendkeys' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.8
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc_sendkeys.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_sendkeys.obj
_sendkeys.c
_sendkeys.c(150): warning C4013: 'Py_InitModule' undefined; assuming extern returning int
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\ATLMFC\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" user32.lib kernel32.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__sendkeys build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_sendkeys.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\_sendkeys.cp38-win32.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_sendkeys.cp38-win32.lib
LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol PyInit__sendkeys
build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_sendkeys.cp38-win32.lib : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lnzycfzs\\sendkeys\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-lnzycfzs\\sendkeys\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ak2dcxbs\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe `sendkeys` doesn't support python 3.8, which is relatively new.

Answer (score 1):

[[PyPI]: SendKeys](https://pypi.org/project/SendKeys) is ancient, the last (and only) version was released ***16+* years ago**.

*Python C API* has significantly changed since (check [[Python 3.Docs]: Building C and C++ Extensions](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html)), and is no longer compatible with *SendKeys* (I think only *Python 2* is).

Alternatives:

- Modify *_sendkeys.c* and build it (with *PIP*) from local archive
- Switch to an up to date package (one such example would be [[PyPI]: Pynput](https://pypi.org/project/pynput/))